# Where is the gta-sa.exe file for Steam?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I am trying to install GTA San Andreas multiplayer and currently I'm on the step where I have to downgrade GTA San Andreas to version 1.0 because SA-MP doesn't support later versions. I've downloaded the tool to make this happen but I can't seem to locate my gta-sa.exe file. Btw, I'm using Steam.

Anyone know where that file for Steam is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gta-sa.exe can be found in `Steam\SteamApps\common\Grand Theft Auto San Andreas`.

If you are using [this tool](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1952458) and your GTA is not installed under `C:\Program Files`, make sure you find all the paths in run.bat and edit them to match your installation paths.